Using dynamic selector for ng-content
I am trying to create a component that can host multiple ng-content with different selectors. The usage might be something like this:
<app-sub #sub>
  <div fullscreen>
    <p>Fullscreen</p>
  </div>
  <div id="test">
    <p>Some other content</p>
  </div>
</app-sub>

Where the user can toggle between the different screens:
<button (click)="sub.toggle('test')">Switch to test</button>
<button (click)="sub.toggle()">Switch to fullscreen</button>

For this I built the component that should be capable of doing this:
@if (!activeId) {
<p>In Non Active</p>
<ng-content select="[fullscreen]"></ng-content>
} @else {
<p>In Active with: {{activeId}}</p>
<ng-content select="[id={{activeId}}]"></ng-content>
}

With the toggle:
export class SubComponent {
  protected activeId?: string;

  public toggle(id?: string) {
    this.activeId = id;
  }
}

While the fullscreen content is shown, selecting by the id doesn't work. But if I predefined the id in the "sub" component as such:
<ng-content select="#test"></ng-content>
<!-- or -->
<ng-content select="[id='test']"></ng-content>

Then it works. So basically setting the values at compile time rather than runtime.
How can I achieve that I can select components dynamically?
Here is a stackblitz to play around: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-brmda7

the ng-content selectors are static and evaluated at compile time, which is why dynamically switching between content using selectors like [id={{activeId}}] does not work

Well, I thought so as well. Thanks for the confirmation.

You should not use ng-content inside conditionals. It's in documentation  
Content projection with ng-content.
Instead I recommend using [hidden] attribute to hide and show ng-content.
This simplifies your conditionals to single line, to show/hide the sections.
<div [hidden]="activeId">
  <p>In Non Active</p>
  <ng-content select="[fullscreen]"></ng-content>
</div>
<div [hidden]="!activeId">
  <p>In Active with: {{activeId}}</p>
  <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
</div>

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  input,
  viewChild,
  InputSignal,
  signal,
  WritableSignal,
  Signal,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sub',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="activeId">
      <p>In Non Active</p>
      <ng-content select="[fullscreen]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!activeId">
      <p>In Active with: {{activeId}}</p>
      <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class SubComponent {
  protected activeId?: string;

  public toggle(id?: string) {
    this.activeId = id;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
  <app-sub >
    <div fullscreen>
      <p>Fullscreen</p>
    </div>
    <div content>
      <div id="test1" [hidden]="selector() !== 'test1'">
        <p>Some other content1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="test2" [hidden]="selector() !== 'test2'">
        <p>Some other content2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-sub>
  <button (click)="switchToggle('test1')">Switch to test 1</button>
  <button (click)="switchToggle('test2')">Switch to test 2</button>
  <button (click)="switchToggle()">Switch to fullscreen</button>
  `,
  imports: [SubComponent],
})
export class App {
  sub: Signal<SubComponent | undefined> = viewChild(SubComponent);
  selector: WritableSignal<string | undefined> = signal(undefined);

  switchToggle(selector?: string) {
    this.selector.set(selector);
    this.sub()?.toggle(selector);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

I do like that approach! Much appreciated!
